# Passing variables onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript

Alright guys, i'm trying to use the variable in the `getIndividualMap` function but i'm getting an `undefined` error. What could be the problem?

```
 var i; 
    for(i=0;i<=(data.length -1);i++)
    {   
    $('#ResultsId').append("<table border='1'>" + 

    "<tr>" +
    "<th>UserID</th>" +
    "<th>RUNDATE</th>" +
    "<th>NAME</th>" +
    "<th>TIME</th>" +
    "<th>DISTANCE (KM)</th>" +

    "</tr>" +
    "<tr>" + 
    "<td>" + data[i].UserID + "</td>"  + " " + 
    "<td>" + data[i].runDate + "</td>"  + " " + 
    "<td>" + data[i].firstName + "</td>"  + " " + 
    "<td>" + data[i].Time + "</td>"  + " " + 
    "<td>" + data[i].Distance + "</td>" + 
    "<td>" +"<a href='#' onclick= 'getIndividualMap(i)'>"  + data[i].UserID +"</a>" + "</td>" + 
    "</tr>" + 
    "</table>" );
    }


getIndividualMap(){
console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function parameter Variable missing.....

```
getIndividualMap(i){
console.log(i);
}
```

And in the below portion

```
"<td>" +"<a href='#' onclick= 'getIndividualMap(i)'>"  + data[i].UserID +"</a>" + "</td>" +
```

***i is hard coded, but its  a variable***

It should be

```
"<td>" +"<a href='#' onclick= 'getIndividualMap("+ i + ")'>"  + data[i].UserID +"</a>" + "</td>" +
```